# create xml file, basics

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create xml document with following structure

```
<ServerFp Command="Cashed">
    <Cashed Value="199.99"/>
</ServerFp>
```

So I tried like this :

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("ServerFp");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Command", "Cashed");

            }
```

Is this good so far and how to end this file? with node `<Cashed Value="199.99"/>`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `XmlWriter`, to be honest - any reason you don't want to use LINQ to XML, which would make this trivial?

Comment: no reason :) please post as an answer.

Comment: see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18206227/847349) below. Kinda wrote it longer than it took Jon to comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not just [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx)?

```
XElement ServerFp = new XElement("ServerFp",
    new XAttribute("Command", "Cached"),
    new XElement("CachedValue", "199.99")
);
Console.WriteLine(ServerFp.ToString());
```

outputting

```
<ServerFp Command="Cached">
  <CachedValue>199.99</CachedValue>
</ServerFp>
```

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks! Will update the answer for even more eunoia

Answer (score 4):

I would try doing it like this:

create a new XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
```

create your nodes you want to insert

```
XmlNode node1 = doc.CreateElement("node1")
```

append your element

```
doc.AppendChild(node1 );
```

save the document

```
doc.Save("result.xml");
```

Comment: I wouldn't use XmlDocument - XDocument is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Try this **LINQ To XML**

```
 XElement result = new XElement("ServerFp", new XAttribute("Command", "Cashed"),
                   new XElement("Cashed", new XAttribute("Value", "199.99"))
                   );
```

Output

```
<ServerFp Command="Cashed">
  <Cashed Value="199.99" />
</ServerFp>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can do it by using `XmlWriter`

```
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("ServerFp");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Command", "Cashed");
writer.WriteStartElement("Cashed");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", "199.99");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Or you can do the same using `XDocument`

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("ServerFp", new XAttribute("Command", "Cashed"), 
    new XElement("Cashed", new XAttribute("Value", "199.99"))));

doc.Save(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I am not sure but you can get an idea)

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings))
{
     writer.WriteStartDocument();
     writer.WriteStartElement("ServerFp");
     writer.WriteAttributeString("Command", "Cashed");

     writer.WriteEndElement(); // I think this will close your <Cashed Value="199.99"/>
     writer.WriteEndElement(); // I think this will close your 
}
```